# How to understand this SSSD log?

Tags: logs, sssd

```
(Wed Apr 19 14:16:47 2017) [sssd[be[xx.xx.COM]]] [sdap_get_generic_op_finished] (0x0400): Search result: Referral(10), 0000202B: `RefErr`: DSID-03100781, data 0, 1 access points
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the log structure

```
(<timestamp>) [sssd[<process>[<domain>]]] [<function>] (<debugLevel>) <payload|result>
```

your log snippet and assuming that former log lines had entries like

```
(<timestamp>) [sssd[be[<domain>]]] [sdap_process_message] (0x4000): Message
type: [LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT]
```

it means that you have probably got an

`LdapReferralException` with LDAP error code `10` - `0000202B`, the domain or domain controller wasn't found.

In such case I would recommend to start with checking the search base DN, the configuration property `ldap_referrals=` and have a look into [SSSD issue #3197](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/3197).

[sssd-users mailing list](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/sssd-users@lists.fedorahosted.org/) is good starting point for further research. And for more information regarding `sssd_be` you may have a look into: [Inter-process communication between SSSD processes](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/developers/ipc.html).